# how to disable form submit and check the form

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. I need to see how many checkboxes have been checked in my form and if there are 4 or less submit the form and if there are more display an error and don't submit.

```
function SetHiddenFieldValue() 
{
    var checks = document.getElementById('toppings').getElementsByTagName('input');
    var toppings = new Array();
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000) + 100);
    var totalChecked = 0;
    var itemPrice = 5.99;

    for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
    {
        if (checks[i].checked)
        {
            toppings[i] = checks[i].value;
            totalChecked += 1; 
        }
    }

    if (totalChecked > 4) {
        alert("You can only choose up to Max of 4 Toppings");   
    } else {    
        itemPrice = itemPrice + (totalChecked * 0.99);  
        document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = toppings.join("\t");
        document.getElementById('my-item-id').value = randomNumber;
        document.getElementById('my-item-price').value = itemPrice;
    }
```

And my form is:

```
<form id="pizza" name="pizza" method="post" action="" class="jcart" onsubmit="return SetHiddenFieldValue();">
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" id="my-item-id" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" id="my-item-name" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" id="my-item-price" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" value=" add " />
</form>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your javascript looks correct.  I think the only you should need to do is **return false;** on your **if (totalChecked > 4)** statement.

**Edit**: Here's the section of your javascript function to modify:

```
if (totalChecked > 4) {
    alert("You can only choose up to Max of 4 Toppings");   
    return false;
} else {    
    itemPrice = itemPrice + (totalChecked * 0.99);  
    document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = toppings.join("\t");
    document.getElementById('my-item-id').value = randomNumber;
    document.getElementById('my-item-price').value = itemPrice;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice, but where should the return false be?
I tried to use it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs to return `false` to cancel the submission or `true` to proceed. That's why your `onsubmit` form attribute is set to `"return XXX()"` rather than just `"XXX()"`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you should return false from your check function to cancel the submit, and true if the check is okay.

How about something like this?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Pizza Order Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function SetHiddenFieldValue() {
                var totalChecked = 0;
                var itemPrice = 5.99;
                var toppings = new Array();
                var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000) + 100);
                var checks = document.getElementsByName('topping');

                for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
                    if (checks[i].checked) {
                        toppings[i] = checks[i].value;
                        totalChecked += 1;
                    }
                }

                if (totalChecked > 4) {
                    alert("You can only choose up to Max of 4 Toppings");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    itemPrice = itemPrice + (totalChecked * 0.99);
                    document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = toppings.join("\t");
                    document.getElementById('my-item-id').value = randomNumber;
                    document.getElementById('my-item-price').value = itemPrice;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <form id="pizza" name="pizza" method="post" action="" class="jcart" onsubmit="return SetHiddenFieldValue();">
            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" id="my-item-id" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" id="my-item-name" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" id="my-item-price" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1" />
            <div id="toppings">
                <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="pepperoni" />Pepperoni
                <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="tomato" />Tomato
                <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="mushrooms" />Mushrooms
                <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="peppers" />Peppers
                <input type="checkbox" name="topping" id="olives" />Olives
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" value=" Add " />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```